# app crash on core data save context for first time launch on ios 8 only

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios8, xcode8

i am getting app crash only on ios 8 with core data save context when i launch the app for very first time. other wise app works fine. i have tried number of alternatives with no success. one strange observation was if i put a breakpoint at save context then every thing works fine in ios 8 too. if i disable break point then it get crashed.strange behaviour.

here is my code. getting crash at `try self.subContext.save()` with no message in console

```
func saveCycle(_ arrcycle:NSArray) {
    for dicdata:NSDictionary in arrcycle as! [NSDictionary] {
        do {
            let fetchRequest = self.cycleFetchRequest()
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "cycle_rule_id = %@", argumentArray: [dicdata.value(forKey: KEY_CYCLE_RULES_ID)!])
            let results  = try self.subContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Cycle_Rules]
            if(results.count > 0){
                continue
            }else{
                let cycle = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Cycle_Rules", into: self.subContext) as? Cycle_Rules
                cycle?.setFromDict(dicdata)
                print("crash- save cycle")

                self.saveChildContext()
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            DDLogVerbose("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

override func saveChildContext() {
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(managedObjectContextDidSave(notification:)),
                                   name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextDidSave,
                                   object: subContext)
    self.saveContext()

}

override func saveContext() {

        if self.subContext.hasChanges {
            do {

                try self.subContext.save()

            } catch {

                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full backtrace and crashlog.

Comment: If there is no message in console, are you sure that it really crashes? Maybe it only hits some global exception breakpoint on try, which will be handed if you let it continue?

Comment: yes i am sure it gets crash and only for first time app launch and only on ios 8